# Why do I keep getting this mysql error?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, vba

Hi stackoverflow people!
I have been recently developing a simple vb.net program that connects to a mysql database to register and login users with given credentials. I have used this code to register my users but I keep getting and error (below the code)

```
Dim insertUser As String = "INSERT INTO users(ID, username, password, email, verif)" _
        & " VALUES('','" & Username.Text & "','" & Password.Text & "','" & Email.Text & "','" & currentRandString & "');"
        Dim checkUsername As String = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" & Username.Text & "'"
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection()
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString = mysqlconntxt4reg
        MysqlConn.Open()

        Dim myCommand As New MySqlCommand
        myCommand.Connection = MysqlConn
        myCommand.CommandText = checkUsername

        myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand
        Dim myData As MySqlDataReader
        myData = myCommand.ExecuteReader

        If myData.HasRows > 0 Then
            MsgBox("Username Already In Use...", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
            myData.Close()
        Else
            myData.Close()
            Dim myCommand2 As New MySqlCommand
            myCommand2.Connection = MysqlConn
            myCommand2.CommandText = insertUser

            myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand2
            Dim myData2 As MySqlDataReader
            myData2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader
            Mail(Email.Text, currentRandString)
            Me.Close()
            myData2.Close()
        End If
    Catch myerror As MySqlException
        MsgBox("Error While Connecting To Database:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & myerror.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
```

I have closed all my datareaders before opening other ones so I do not see why this does not work...

Error:
[image]

[Link to Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WozcX.png)

I would appreciate any help on this topic!
Thanks
Rodit

Comment: Probably because there is already an open DataReader associated with that connection.

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - never concatenate SQL this way. Use parameterized queries instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the using statement around all the disposable objects to be sure that they release every references to the connection when they are no more needed, but looking at your code, I think you don't need at all the datareaders because you could resolve your problem just with the commands

```
Dim insertUser As String = "INSERT INTO users(username, password, email, verif)" _
                            & " VALUES(@p1, @p2,@p3,@p4)"
Dim checkUsername As String = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username=@p1"

Using MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection(mysqlconntxt4reg)
Using myCommand = New MySqlCommand(checkUsername, MysqlConn)
    MysqlConn.Open()
    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Username.Text)
    Dim result = myCommand.ExecuteScalar()
    if result IsNot Nothing AndAlso Convert.ToInt32(result) > 0 Then
         MsgBox("Username Already In Use...", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error")
    Else
        Using myCommand2 = New MySqlCommand(insertUser, MysqlConn)
               mycommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1",Username.Text)
               mycommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2",Password.Text )
               mycommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3",Email.Text) 
               mycommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4",currentRandString )
               myCommand2.ExecuteNonQuery()
               Mail(Email.Text, currentRandString)
        End Using      
    End If
End Using
End Using
```

Of course I have replaced your string concatenations with a parameterized query. This is really an important thing to do to avoid Sql Injection

I have replaced the query that checks the user existence with a scalar operation that can be used with the command ExecuteScalar. Also, in the first query, it seems that you try to insert the field ID with an empty string. I think that the first field (ID) is an autonumber field and, in this case, you don't add it to the insert query and don't pass any value because the database will calculate that field for you.

Comment: on this line Using (MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection(mysqlconntxt4reg))   I get this error: Operator '=' is not defined for types 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' and 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection'

Comment: Actually now I get a nullreference excepion problem... Please help me!

Comment: When I click register button it gives me object reference not set to instance of object

Comment: On which line? This could easily spotted using the debugger. Set a breakpoint on the first line of code and run the app, when the code reach the breakpoint proceed step by step until you find the null variable that triggers the error